# How to create specific query for mysql with python 3

Tags: python

I have a array which contains the column name of my table

```
column_names_list = ['TIMESTAMP', 'ID', 'PRENOM',  'AGE', 'HOB']
```

i want to create a string which contains the query that can be executed with **cursor.execute** from python
For example

```
def prepare_request( self, table_name, database) :
    column_names_list = ['TIMESTAMP', 'ID', 'PRENOM',  'AGE', 'HOB']
    print ( column_names_list ) 
    column_values = ["%s" for x in column_names_list]
    print ( column_values ) 
    request = "INSERT INTO "+database+"."+table_name+"("+column_names_list+")+ VALUES ("+column_values+");"
    print(request)
```

When i execute the code, i get this error => TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

**Output expected:**

```
INSERT INTO TEST.USERS ( TIMESTAMP , ID , PRENOM, AGE, HOB ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);
```

Comment: `" VALUES ("+(column_values)` attempts to concatenate the string `" VALUES ("` to the _list_ `column_values`. This is not allowed, the only thing that can be concatenated to a string is another string. Same for `"("+column_names_list`:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `join()` your values:

```
def prepare_request( self, table_name, database) :
    column_names_list = ['TIMESTAMP', 'ID', 'PRENOM',  'AGE', 'HOB']
    print ( column_names_list ) 
    column_values = ["%s" for x in column_names_list]
    print ( column_values ) 
    request = "INSERT INTO "+database+"."+table_name+" VALUES "+", ".join(column_values)+");"
    print(request)
```

But also, the `column_values = ["%s" for x in column_names_list]` is not really doing anything but creating a list with `len(column_names_list)` values where each one is `"%s"`.

Comment: I get this error in you code :   print(request)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, I left an extra opening parenthese, I edited my core. However I recommend you to take a look on Gabip's answer below, the f-strings are way better than this kind of concatenation.

Comment: you forget '(' after values, then you code works fine

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
request = f"INSERT INTO {database}.{table_name} ({",".join(column_names_list)}) VALUES ({",".join(column_values)});"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the second last line with the following code-

```
request = "INSERT INTO "+database+"."+table_name+str(tuple(column_names_list))+"+ VALUES "+str(tuple(column_values))+";"
```

Actually, you are getting problem because column_names_list and column_values are lists and they can't be concatenated with strings. What I did here is to convert them into strings first using str() function. Hope it was helpful.